# Models of $T$ in cardinallity $\kappa$ are isomorphic

Tags: model-theory

Assume that $T$ is a consistent set in a countable language $\mathscr{L}$ with no finite models. There is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that every two models of $T$ with cardinallity of $\kappa$ are isomorphic. Show that for every closed formula (i.e without free variables), $\varphi$, one and only one of the sets $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$, $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ is consistent.

I guess I should use the Compactness Theorem, but I can't see how exactly.

Would like to have some help here.

Comment: For future reference, it is often called Vaught's test and it is a very handy way to prove that a theory is complete.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem. If a theory over a countable language has an infinite model, then it has a model of cardinality $\kappa$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$,

Comment: I'm not sure how Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem is relevant. It seems that if $m$ is a model of $T$ then if $m\vDash \varphi$ is not true, then we must have $m\nvDash \varphi$ therefore $m\vDash \neg \varphi$ which means that $T\cup {\neg \varphi }$ satisfied by $m$.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I got it.

Assume that both of the sets, $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\},T\cup\{\varphi\}$ are consistent.
Then since $\mathscr L$, they have models from every cardinallity (from Lowenheim-Skolem). Take them from cardinallity $\kappa$.

Then $m_{1}$ is a model of $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ of cardinallity $\kappa$, and $m_{2}$ is a model of $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ of cardinallity $\kappa$.

Particullary, $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ are models of $T$ from cardinallity $\kappa$ therefore they are isomorphic (given) and so they should satisfy the same closed formuals, which a contraction ($\varphi$ is the witness for that...).

Now, ok, so both of the sets can't be consistent. therefore it's only of them, or no one of them. Is it even possible that no of them will be consistent?

Comment: There **is** a model, and in that model $\varphi$ is either true or false. If it is true, then $T$ plus $\varphi$ is consistent. If it  false in the model then $T$ plus $\lnot\varphi$ is consistent.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you want to use `\neg \varphi` not `\not\varphi`.

Comment: Thanks, I had intended to use \lnot, left out the l. Luckily your message came in the $5$ minute editing window.

Comment: Andre, I don't understand why your first reply here is not enough for the whole proof. What's missing? T has a model, in which $\varphi$ could be true or false, therefore only one of the sets is consistent. I can't see what's missing ..

Comment: We also need the Loweheim-Skolem argument that you gave. For we need to show either $\varphi$ is true in **every** model, or $\lnot\varphi$ is true in every model. So we argue exactly as you did that if $T$ plus $\varphi$ is consistent, then there is a model of cardinality $\kappa$ in which it is true, and if $T$ plus $\lnot\varphi$ has a model of cardinality $\kappa$. But all models of cardinality $\kappa$ are isomorphic, so we cannot have both consistent.

Comment: An important example is the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$. It can be proved by algebraic means that any two models of cardinality $\gt \aleph_0$ are isomorphic, so by the result we are proving the theory is complete.